# How to merge only once when master branch diverged?

Tags: git, git-merge

let's consider following scenario in local git repository that is synced with remote:

```
──(A)─┬─(B)── master
      │
      └─(C)── branch
```

after merge branch into master (locally, takes long time since (C)= many commits):

```
──(A)─┬─(B)─┬─(D)── master
      │     │
      └─(C)─┘  branch
```

During the merge this happened on the remote repository:

```
──(A)───(B)───(E)── master
```

Now, I want to have this result:

```
──(A)─┬─(B)─┬─(D)──(E)── master
      │     │
      └─(C)─┘  branch
```

or this result

```
──(A)─┬─(B)───(E)─┬──(F)── master
      │           │
      └────(C)────┘  branch
```

i.e. I do not want more merge lines.
Is that possible to do without spending long of time by merging lot of stuff (C) once again?

Comment: Let me try to understand this, you want to avoid having to merge `C` again because it takes so long? Do you know why merging `C` takes so long? It seems strange that it would.

Comment: If you have already done merge; that means you branch is 2 commits behind and 1 commit ahead.  Now if you do git pull (or fetch and rebase origin/branchname) those to commits will get attached to C as D--E. so where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If someone pushed code to your remote that looks like this

```
──(A)───(B)───(E)── master
```

then that is ***public*** history, and you shouldn't rewrite it unless the other developers working on the project with you are ok with that, and won't be troubled by having to sync their work up with the new rewritten history. If they're not ok with you rewriting their history, then you shouldn't do this

```
──(A)─┬─(B)─┬─(D)──(E)── master
      │     │
      └─(C)─┘  branch
```

because then `E` becomes a child of `D` instead of `B`, which is not what is in the public history.

What most people would do in this situation is to just undo the merge locally with a hard reset, then re-merge or rebase against the new tip of master from the remote. Let's assume you just re-merge, then your history will look like this, as you've described:

```
──(A)─┬─(B)───(E)─┬──(F)── master
      │           │
      └────(C)────┘  branch
```

or you could rebase `C` against `E` to get something more linear, like this:

```
───(A)───(B)───(E)───(C')── master
```

Without more information though, I wouldn't not be able to help you figure out a way to avoid merging `C` take so long, I don't know why you're having that problem.

Comment: For the first part: you are right, let's not consider this case then. The issue is that there are many conflicts in many files.

Comment: How about rebasing then? You'll have to resolve the same number of conflicts, but every time you have a need to rebase afterwards (like if someone pushes more commits to your remote `master`), then those conflicts will already have been resolved, and you'd only have to resolve any new conflicts that come up.

Comment: With rebasing you are right, but sice a branch with many changes is about to be merged, I prefer preserving the original branch history. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do what you want. As previously stated, most of the 
time people will just undo the merge and redo it based on the new state of the 
upstream branch. But, it can be done.

If you currently have a `master` branch which has your merge as the latest 
commit and `origin/master` which has the recent development from other people 
you can do the following to make it look like you did the merge on top of 
current `origin/master` rather than the old version:

```
git checkout master
git branch savepoint
git merge -m temporary origin/master
git reset --hard $(git show --pretty=format:%B 'HEAD^' | git commit-tree -p 'HEAD^2' -p 'HEAD^^2' -F - 'HEAD^{tree}')
```

The visible merge there will create an additional merge commit, but that will 
be going away with the following command. That merge is only done to get the 
desired final state of the repository contents.

The final command there is a complex one. The `commit-tree` portion creates 
another merge commit which has commits E and C as the parents, the repository 
contents created by the previous merge operation, and the commit message from 
the merge that you had previously done (thanks to the `show` command and the 
`-F -` option). Then the `reset` causes this new merge commit to become the new 
state. This should give you the first option of the desired results, and it 
won't rewrite any history that has been shared.

Since this uses `git reset --hard` this will obliterate any uncommitted 
changes. The `savepoint` branch was created just to have a convenient was to 
backup to the starting point in case something goes wrong.